# how to restart activity when device's screen unlocked in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, locking, keyevent

I have 4 activity:

- FirstActivity - it shows in the first time of app running
- MainActivity
- SeconActivity
- ThirdActivity

I want to show `FirstActivity` when Power Button clicked and user unlocked his/her  phone. but how can i handle it that after showing `FirstActivity` BackgroundActivity shows again.
how can i do it?

for example in `MainActivity`:

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        Intent checkingIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstActivity.class);
        checkingIntent.putExtra("checking",true);
        startActivity(checkingIntent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and in FirstActivity

```
public boolean checking() {
    checking_FOR_bankInfo= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("checking");
    if (checking_FOR_bankInfo){
        ...
    }
    return cdo_state;
}
```

Comment: Put the code of how you start `FirstActivity` again.

Comment: i don't know how to do it

Comment: after `startActivity(checkingIntent);` this add `finish();` to your code and try it.

Comment: means it will finish previous activity.

Comment: i do it,but nothing happens

Comment: ok. other method I will check it and give you..

Comment: oh thanks. i wait for you.

Comment: @NitinPatel. did you delete your answer? i accept and vote up your answer! why you delete it?

Comment: Simple advice as genuine developer that accept answer or useful comment as reward instead of just writing "Thanks".

Comment: yes, there is a problem in my internet connection that reject my acceptation, but i promise myself to do it again as soon as its OK. it is not my fault!!!

Comment: yes, there is a problem in my internet connection that reject my acceptation, but i promise myself to do it again as soon as its OK. it is not my fault!!!

Comment: yes, there is a problem in my internet connection that reject my acceptation, but i promise myself to do it again as soon as its OK. it is not my fault!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in every activity's `onPause()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean screenOn;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        screenOn = pm.isInteractive();
    } else {
        screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    }
    if (!screenOn) {    //Screen off by lock or power
        Intent checkingIntent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        checkingIntent.putExtra("checking",true);
        checkingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(checkingIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please give me some information about `Flag`.

Comment: Accept this as answer.

Comment: These all links will guide and knowledge you. (1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/19627387/7806873  (2)https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int)   (3)https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Its OK. Not a problem.

Comment: if i press RECENT APPS button and relaunch the app,how can i start the `checkingIntent`?

Comment: I think it should start in `checkingIntent`.

Comment: When pause function called it stops current activity and starts `FirstActivity`. Then whenever screen come back it resume in `FirstActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() 
    {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(tag, "MYonStop is called");
        // insert here your instructions
        // you can call new activity here.


    }
```

when you press the button HOME the onStop() method is called.

Comment: how about power/lock button? also e.g. if i start BActivity, AActivity is finish/stop automatically and i will have problem with this method!